# Do iOS/UIKit controls automatically change their styling for different iOS versions?

Tags: ios, uikit

Sorry if I use the wrong terminology, I'm not an iOS developer so I'm mapping everything back to equivalent features in Windows ...

If I write an iOS application that creates controls using standard UIKit functions, and I run that exact same application on various versions of iOS, will the application look slightly different on the different versions of iOS?  Or does the application always use the styling of the version of iOS I select for the target version in Xcode?

And in a related question, is there a web site somewhere showing how the various controls have changed their look through the various iOS versions?

Comment: The only difference came in iOS 7.0 when iOS switched to the flat look. Since there is no reason to support anything before iOS 7.0, there's nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally no. Since iOS7 to current iOS release - all standard UIKit controls look the same. On iOS6 and lower things are drastically different. If you target iOS7 and up (As most devs do now since hardly anyone is on iOS versions lower) - you can be rest assured that all usage of standard UIKit controls will look exactly the same.

Comment: The default system font has changed in iOS 9, so if you don't use a non-default font then the text in your app will look different.

Comment: Fine. But we're talking about UIKit controls here. Not system fonts. Which as you correctly stated has changed.

Comment: BTW, the concern from management is more about the next version rather than the previous version, to wit: if the next version of iOS does make some change to control styles, will our application automatically look like the new version?  Or will it continue looking like the current version, and immediately we have an application that looks "out of date"?

Comment: The chances of Apple changing UIKit controls and overall look again is highly unlikely. If they were, to do it. just like in iOS 6 to iOS7 move.. apps running on the newer iOS will look different, yes. You may have to make some changes for compatibility. But again.. the chances of this happening is highly unlikely. Apple have only done a major change like this once.

Comment: And to Tander's point about iOS 6 vs. iOS 7 - let's pretend, for the sake of discussion, that I had asked this question while iOS 6 was the current version.  If we had released an app then, would that app run on an iOS 7 platform, and if so would its controls look like iOS 6 or like iOS 7?

Comment: As above. It will show the newer controls on iOS7. And the old controls on iO6

Comment: Sorry to add - yes, it would have run. But you may have had to fix a few minor things if you defeated from standard UIKit controls a lot. Most apps just worked with the new layout Apple did. Ours did too - we jus had to tweak it a little.